# mootools or javascript : what does $tmp stand for or what does it pertain too

Tags: javascript, mootools

I'm currently working on the `Tips.js` from `mootools` library and my code breaks on the line that has those `el.$tmp`, and console says it's undefined

Can anybody help me?

Comment: "$tmp" is just a property name. JavaScript variables/properties can being with a "$". Can you show us some code excerpts of what you're doing? Seems to me like an API-misuse, causing MooTools to puke when a property it assumes should be set is not set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in 1.11 (haven't checked in 1.2+) $tmp is a reference to the element itself, created and used internally by the garbage collector:

```
var Garbage = {

    elements: [],

    collect: function(el){
        if (!el.$tmp){
            Garbage.elements.push(el);
            el.$tmp = {'opacity': 1};
        }
        return el;
    },

    trash: function(elements){
        for (var i = 0, j = elements.length, el; i < j; i++){
            if (!(el = elements[i]) || !el.$tmp) continue;
            if (el.$events) el.fireEvent('trash').removeEvents();
            for (var p in el.$tmp) el.$tmp[p] = null;
            for (var d in Element.prototype) el[d] = null;
            Garbage.elements[Garbage.elements.indexOf(el)] = null;
            el.htmlElement = el.$tmp = el = null;
        }
        Garbage.elements.remove(null);
    },

    empty: function(){
        Garbage.collect(window);
        Garbage.collect(document);
        Garbage.trash(Garbage.elements);
    }

};
```

the lines `el.$tmp = {'opacity': 1};` (in collect method above) and `el.htmlElement = el.$tmp = el = null;` (in trash method above) are the only places in the source where this property is assigned that i could find, although it's called by various other methods, such as Element.setOpacity and Element.getStyle (specifically, only to return opacity value), as well as methods in the Tips class

1.2 might not have this issue, but in any case, hope that helps and sorry i couldn't help more

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest taking your question and posting it, along with a link to the page to either/or/and:

http://mooforum.net

http://groups.google.com/group/mootools-users/topics

That's the community that swarms with it.

Now as for answering it here - I'd need a lot more information (code example?)

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm. I'm not exactly sure what el.$tmp is a reference to in MooTools but a message stating "console is undefined" is probably because someone was trying to log to the Firebug (or another) console and that object does not exist if you don't have Firebug and friends.

If you don't have http://getfirebug.com'>Firebug installed for Firefox then you might give it a shot. See if you can find the console statement and remove it. Also, if you aren't using Firefox, you can use Firebug Lite in IE, Safari, or Opera.

Comment: he said that the console was saying that el.$tmp is undefined, not that console was undefined.